# R - create large graphics device (override dimensions limit)

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to create a large plot which requires huge dimensions of the plot area. I figured out the best way to do this is to create a new graphics device. However, there seems to be some sort of a limit on how large the graphics device can be. In order to demonstrate my issue, I will first create a graphics device with some usual dimensions (not too large):

```
dev.new(width = 5, height = 5, noRStudioGD = T)
```

If I want to inspect the size of the device I can use:

```
dev.size()
```

The output is the following:

```
[1] 4.916667 4.916667
```

Which tells us that the dimensions of 5x5 are approximately met. Now if I try to create a larger device:

```
dev.new(width = 800, height = 800, noRStudioGD = T)

dev.size()
```

Output:

```
[1] 9.479167 9.479167
```

It seems that the graphics device is unable to go beyond approximately 10x10 size dimensions. Since this is way too small for the plot that I need, I was wondering how can I alter this imposed limit and increase my graphics device size?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the type of device you're creating. It looks like you're trying to specify size in pixels, but the device you're creating may be specified in sizes of inches, centimeters, etc. From the docs, it says the default device created is specified by getOption("device") (check `?dev.new`). I think you'd be able to create a default device (with `dev.new`), then get the device types (with `dev.list`), then do `?type of device` shown from the list to get more details. i.e. for me,

```
> dev.new()
> dev.list()
X11
  2
> ?X11
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed your advice and I found out that the type of the graphics device I am creating is `windows`. I checked the documentation (`?windows`) and it says:  _A graphics window is not allowed to be specified at more that 85% of the screen width or height: the width and height are rescaled proportionally._. So, how do I go on from here? I really need to create a device which is larger than 85% of my screen

Comment: What you mention in your comment references the "graphics window", not necessarily the "graphics device". I'm not sure if there are rendering limits on the size of rendered image (except for the limits of your RAM), but I assume if you specified a 50" x 50" image render in a `png()` call that creates the device/etc, you'd be able to save it to a file and go from there. But, I'd check the docs.